# Updating ImageView in a Fragment Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've one MainActivity, and few fragments on it.

I am trying to change a ImageView in a fragment using Gallery. But once image is selected, the MainActivity get refresh, which changes the MainActivity back to the default fragment.

Getting permission

```
 textViewChangeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Select Image executed");

            requestPermissions(
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_CODE);



        }
    });
```

On Request permission

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Select Image Permission executed");

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
        progressDialogUploadDp.setMessage("Uploading...");
       progressDialogUploadDp.show();

        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra("imageUpdate","true");
            startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return;
    }

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

On Activity Result

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null){

        try {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        StorageReference filepath =
                storageReference.child("Photos").child("DPs").child(ID).child("profilepicture.jpg");
            InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imageviewpropic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    progressDialogUploadDp.hide();
                    progressDialogUploadDp.dismiss();


                }
            });

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Looking forward for a solution!

Updated ---

MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState==null) {
mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("questioners")) {
adapter = new SectionStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                                    adapter.addFragment(new HomeFragment(), "HomeFragment");
                                    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
}
```

Comment: Check in your Developer settings have you selected Do Not Keep Activities, because this issue would occut if this option is enabled

Comment: Yes, its unchecked.

Comment: Provide code for entire acivity. Also do what Akshay says, it might help

Comment: MainActivity Code added!

Answer (score 1):

Back form gallery , activity will run onActivityResult then it will run onResume .
so you can set a FLAG at onActivityResult and make an IF in onResume to set your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've said it looks like your activity is calling onCreate method and setting default fragment again. What you can do is to in onCreate() create new fragment only if there is no saved state.

```
if(savedInstanceState==null) setFragment(fragment);
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the issue. I tried adding if(savedInstanceState==null) but the default fragment code still get executed.